# How to make a loop that prints out first one letter, then two on a new line, etc - javascript

Tags: javascript

So i am a beginner and i have an exercise that intructs the following: 
Make a program that asks for a text and then prints the text several times. First with just one letter, then two, and so on. For example: the user enters "Thomas" and the strings "T", "Th", "Tho", "Thom", "Thoma", "Thomas" are printed.

We are supposed to work with javascript only, here is the code i have so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="eng">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Exercise </title>


    </head>

    <body>
        <h1>Exercise </h1>

        <!-- Form for alert button that shows result -->
        <form>
            <textarea id="mytext" rows="5" cols="20">Type here</textarea>
            <input type="button" value="Print" onclick="printit()" />
        </form>

        <div id="translated" style="background-color: gray"></div>

        <script>
        //Function for getting the result and defining the 2 numbers
            function printit() 
            {
                var temptext = document.getElementById("mytext").value;
                alert(temptext.length)
                temptext = temptext.slice(0,0+1);

                document.getElementById("translated").innerHTML=temptext;

                for (var i = 0; i < temptext; i++) 
                {
                    temptext = temptext.slice(0,0+1);
                    document.getElementById("translated").innerHTML += temptext;
                }

            }
        </script>
    </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++){
  console.log(data.substr(0,i+1));
}
```

where the data is the input get from user.
You want something like this?

Comment: Yes exactly, whatever word the user types in should be returned with first one letter, then to and so on.

Comment: Yes that's what you want (upvote if helped please) @OscarF